# Can I query formula fields in SOQL?

Tags: soql, formula-field

I have a custom object with a custom formula field. When I try to query that field, I get an error.

[image]

```
% sfdx force:data:soql:query --query "SELECT FullNamePrimary__c FROM LoanBorrower__c"
Querying Data... done
ERROR running force:data:soql:query:  
SELECT FullNamePrimary__c FROM LoanBorrower__c
       ^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:8
No such column 'FullNamePrimary__c' on entity 'LoanBorrower__c'...
```

Are formula fields *not* available from SOQL? Is this documented somewhere (yes, I did check the [formula field documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.formula_field_limits.htm&type=5) on the limits, there was no mention of this limitation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Formula fields are most certainly available in SOQL.

Your authenticated user almost certainly does not have Field-Level Security (FLS) access to this field. When you access Salesforce via the API, FLS is enforced against your user, which typically produces this exact error.

Comment: This typically happens when you create a field in one org, and then deploy it to another org. The field will be deployed, but the FLS is a separate thing. Deploying profiles has always been a pain. The two main options here are to 1) Create the field from scratch in your target org 2) Use a PermissionSet to include the permission to read and/or write your field (and then assign it to people in your target org).

Comment: ty, for some reason out of dozens of fields in that table the _only_ ones not available were the formula fields, so I assumed _that_ was the reason.